# "Everybody hurts sometimes."

Tags: sentence-meaning

When we say

> "Everybody hurts sometimes"

does it sound/suggest it has a passive-voice meaning too even though it is written grammatically in active voice.

Does have both meaning that " people can harm other people " and " people can be affected in bad way/ harmed by other people's bad behaviors".

---

Normally I know we say :

> 1. I never meant to hurt your feelings.

( to cause someone emotional pain )Active voice

or

> 2. Fred’s knees hurt after skiing all day.

( to feel pain somewhere in your body ) Active voice

So can we rewrite the latter sentence

> 3. Fred's knees get hurt after skiing all day.

. (Passive voice)

What is the difference between sentence 2 and sentence 3 ?

Example sentences were cited from [Macmillan Dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/hurt_1).

Comment: Have you heard "everybody hurts sometimes" anywhere that gave rise to your question? If so, "details, please".

Comment: Is this question possibly related to the lyrics to _"Everybody Hurts,"_ by R.E.M?  If so, you're missing an "s."  http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/rem/everybodyhurts.html

Comment: @Adam It is but actually I am 'inspired' :) by the song. I would like to learn how to use the word 'hurt' properly that has been making me confused years

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Everybody hurts sometimes

just means that people (in general) sometimes feels good and sometimes feel bad (having some pain or difficulty or such, collectively *hurts*). As written it is a set phrase that would be understood this way.

> 2) Fred’s knees hurt after skiing all day.

is fine. But I wouldn't use *get* in 3.

You could say something like:

> Fred's knees **were hurting** after skiing all day.
>   Fred's knees **started to hurt** after skiing all day.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.So we cannot use the verb hurt in passive voice.So "everybody hurts" has two meanings.

Comment: You could say "Did you *get hurt*? supposing some possibility, but in an actual statement of fact either you hurt or you don't.

Comment: I think people can hurt and get hurt but things only hurt includes our body parts according to your answer.

Comment: Can we say "did you get hurt yourself" and "did you hurt yourself" both?

Comment: _"I heard you were in a car crash that killed two people.  Did you get hurt yourself?"_  The _yourself_ is not totally necessary.  It doesn't change the overall meaning, but does redirect the emphasis back to the person at whom the question is directed.

Comment: @murat _"Did you hurt yourself?"_ In this one, the yourself has a stronger role (specifying _who_ is hurt.)  This phrase is very, very commonly used by parents.  Child trips and falls down, parent says _"Oh, poor thing.  Did you hurt yourself?"_

Comment: @Adam I got your points . What would you say when you see your friend whose arm was wrapped by bandage: " how did you hurt " , " how did you get hurt" , " how were you hurt" or " How are you hurt"

Comment: **A** _"How did you hurt"_ - No good.  _"How did you hurt your arm?"_ would be fine.  **B.**  _"How did you get hurt?_  Means: What was the chain of events leading to your injury? **C** _"How were you hurt"_  Meaning:  same as "How did you get hurt."  **D** _"How are you hurt?"_ Meaning: In what way are you hurt?  (Broken Arm?  Broken arm?  Sprained wrist?)

Comment: @Murat Yes, *hurt* can be used in the passive voice: *He was hurt by falling rocks* or *She was hurt by what he said*, for example.

Comment: I'm surprised that no one has mentioned that the "hurts" of "everybody hurts sometimes" is *ergative*.  In the active voice it takes an agent or actor for its subject and a direct object for its patient, when it has an object.  When it doesn't have an object, it takes a patient as its *subject*.